# Grid in a TabPanel missing its header

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm currently using GXT 3.1.1 to display a TabPanel with two tabs. The second tab comprises a Grid within a VerticalLayoutContainer. My issue is that the header row of the grid isn't displayed.
When I reverse the order of the tabs (i.e when the grid is in the first tab displayed), it is correctly displayed.
Has anyone met the same issue? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I've had a similar problem

Try this when you change tab:

```
table.getView().getHeader().refresh();
```